# How to get captured image of custom renderer camera in iOS xamarin forms

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, ios-camera

We are using a custom camera in our application. I have implemented the custom camera using the below-mentioned link. When clicking the capture button the camera preview is stopped and it's working fine but how can I get the captured image data and I want to save the image in the gallery and return the path. I have got the captured image data in android by using PictureCallback. Please help me with this.

**Custom Camera Link:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this blog](https://medium.com/@quangtqag/simple-photo-capture-using-avcapturesession-b531c2f090b3).
To get the image data in the `AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate`, I added `AVCapturePhotoOutput photoOutput`. Here is an example:

```
public class UICameraPreview : UIView
{
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer previewLayer;
    CameraOptions cameraOptions;

    AVCapturePhotoOutput photoOutput;

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Tapped;

    public AVCaptureSession CaptureSession { get; private set; }

    public bool IsPreviewing { get; set; }

    public UICameraPreview (CameraOptions options)
    {
        cameraOptions = options;
        IsPreviewing = false;
        Initialize ();
    }

    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();

        if (previewLayer != null)
            previewLayer.Frame = Bounds;
    }

    public override void TouchesBegan (NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesBegan (touches, evt);
        OnTapped ();
    }

    protected virtual void OnTapped ()
    {
        var eventHandler = Tapped;
        if (eventHandler != null) {
            eventHandler (this, new EventArgs ());
        }
    }

    void Initialize ()
    {
        CaptureSession = new AVCaptureSession ();
        previewLayer = new AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer (CaptureSession) {
            Frame = Bounds,
            VideoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.ResizeAspectFill
        };

        //self.photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: AVCapturePhotoSettings(), delegate: self)

        photoOutput = new AVCapturePhotoOutput();
        
        CaptureSession.AddOutput(photoOutput);

        photoOutput.CapturePhoto(AVCapturePhotoSettings.Create(),new myDelegate());

        var videoDevices = AVCaptureDevice.DevicesWithMediaType (AVMediaType.Video);
        var cameraPosition = (cameraOptions == CameraOptions.Front) ? AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front : AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back;
        var device = videoDevices.FirstOrDefault (d => d.Position == cameraPosition);

        if (device == null) {
            return;
        }

        NSError error;
        var input = new AVCaptureDeviceInput (device, out error);
        CaptureSession.AddInput (input);
        Layer.AddSublayer (previewLayer);
        CaptureSession.StartRunning ();
        IsPreviewing = true;
    }
}

public class myDelegate : AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {

    public override void DidFinishCapture(AVCapturePhotoOutput captureOutput, AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings resolvedSettings, NSError error)
    {
        base.DidFinishCapture(captureOutput, resolvedSettings, error);
    }

    public override void DidFinishProcessingPhoto(AVCapturePhotoOutput output, AVCapturePhoto photo, NSError error)
    {
        base.DidFinishProcessingPhoto(output, photo, error);

        if (error == null)
        {
            var photodata = photo.FileDataRepresentation;
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't translated all of the swift code to c#, feel free to ask me if you have any questions.

Comment: I have getting **You_Should_Not_Call_base_In_This_Method** exception.

Comment: Remove the        `base.DidFinishProcessingPhoto(output, photo, error);`
 and         `base.DidFinishCapture(captureOutput, resolvedSettings, error);` in the methods in delegate.

Comment: Again I am getting **[AVCapturePhotoOutput capturePhotoWithSettings: delegate:] No active and enabled video connection** exception.

Comment: Can you please have a try to put a button there and call         `photoOutput.CapturePhoto(AVCapturePhotoSettings.Create(),new myDelegate());`
in that button event as mentioned in that blog. Please follow that blog to get the image data:). Will update my answer later.